# Django Rest Framework duplicate key value violates unique constraint when using UserProfile create signal

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So i have created a signal that automatically creates a UserProfile every time i create a new User in my admin.

Code looks like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

Everything works fine, until i try creating a UserProfile extended model in my Django Rest Framework API.

I then get a `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

```
<h1>IntegrityError at /api/v1/space/</h1>
<pre class="exception_value">duplicate key value violates unique constraint &quot;users_userprofile_user_id_key&quot;
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(61) already exists.
</pre>
```

If i remove the signal then the API works fine but then the admin wont be able to automatically create user profiles.

What am i doing wrong? Whats the correct approach?

I believe this is a common issue although i couldn't find any reports of it..

I am using Django 1.7.1

UPDATE:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    avatar = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.Multimedia', blank=True, null=True,
        related_name='user_profiles_avatares'
    )
    language = models.ForeignKey('core.Language', blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = CountryField(blank=True, default='PT')
    about_me = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    facebook_token = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    space_themed_motivation = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    last_login_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Space(UserProfile):
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    galleries = models.ManyToManyField('core.Gallery', blank=True, null=True)
    contents = models.ManyToManyField('core.Multimedia', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: I think the appropriate way to do this is create you own custom user. It's very easy. 1 to 1's in general should be avoided when possible. And creating custom user's isn't particularly hard or difficult and avoids a lot of this messiness.

Comment: @user2734679 i see, but this is legacy code, so i cant really change that much.. dont you know of a way around this?

Comment: can you include the model of your user_profile? are u overriding the save method? For DRF are you using ViewSets, Views, mixins or what?.

Comment: @djangozone i have updated with the code you asked. i am using `ModelViewSet` and i am not overriding the save method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to create a User when creating a UserProfile through your API? If so, how is your create method in your modelviewset? If you are using the default, I guess you are sending the User in your post request. So the flow here when creating a UserProfile should be:

1. Send the POST request with the User id. This User is **already** created.
2. UserProfile is created in your view.
3. Since User was created **before** it shouldn't trigger this 'post_save' signal.

What I guess it may be happening:

1. You User instance is not created when you send your request.
2. The serializer validation pass because everything is OK.
3. When creating the UserProfile, since your User relation can't be null, it creates a User instance, triggering the signal and creating your UserProfile.
4. After creating the User instance, it tries to save the new UserProfile instance but it can't because it already exists in the db (created by the post_save signal in the User model).

I attach here the source code of the create method with respective comments:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)

    if serializer.is_valid(): # It passes because here there are no new objects created yet
        self.pre_save(serializer.object)
        self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True) # It creates the User (triggering the signal) instance and then when saving UserProfile, it give the integrity error
        self.post_save(self.object, created=True)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What I recommend:

1. Change your signal to be executed when you create a new UserProfile so it adds a new User. This is the normal way to do this (at least what I use to do). This will work both in admin and in your api.
2. If 1 is not possible, instead of offering the UserProfile endpoint, do it with the User. This way, it will work exactly as in your admin.
3. If 1 and 2 are not possible, override the create method and **only** create the User instance. The problem with this is that the profile will be empty as when creating it in your admin

Comment: thanks for the answer. i am still unsure which recomedation i am going to use because in the admin i need to add USER and then USERPROFILE, but in my API i need to add USERPROFILE and only then the USER. Its the opposite.

Comment: i might end up giving priority to the API and in the admin always the the association manually when needed since it will be used less

Comment: You can try to override the create method so you can create the User instance before UserProfile is saved. This may work.

Comment: that override seems a bit hacky so i am a bit scared. do you have an example on how i can force the creation of a foreign key first?

Comment: Aight, ignore the previous comment. As I said this override would work but your UserProfile instance would be empty because it is created with the post_save signal of the User class so the data passed through the api would be ignored. I would recommend giving priority to the API. Btw, in admin, you can still add the user through the UserProfile form.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may down to using get_or_create, you should just use create i.e.

```
UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: i have tried with `create`only and i get the same error

Comment: do you have any more ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you able to add the full stack trace for this unique constraint violation to your question above? That could well give more clues.

Comment: i have updated the code above with the stack trace but i am not sure it will help